# How to arrange divs side by side?

Tags: php, html, css, stylesheet

I tried many tips available on the web but failed . I'm a student and not good in programming.
I need to show upto 10 divs in a page 5 on 1st row and another 5 in 2nd . 'Float:right;'
property and 'clear:none; ' in css is not working on this. Is there any other way to do this ?

this is my code :-

```
<div  class="center_full">   
 <?php 

 $q= mysql_query("select * from uploads where artist=".$_SESSION['id']." limit $l,10 ");
 while($my_uploads=mysql_fetch_array($q))
  {

  $image=$my_uploads['img_name'];
 $description=$my_uploads['description'];
 $paint_size=$my_uploads['paint_width']." * ".$my_uploads['paint_height'];
 $likes=$my_uploads['vote_up'];
 $price=$my_uploads['price'];


  ?>
  <div id="product_wrapper" >     <!-- _______this is the div, I want to arrange_______ -->


 <table class="boxed_table fixed_product">
 <tr>
 <td>
 <img id="smple_img" src="uploads/<?php echo $image; ?>"  /> 
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <h5> Description : </h5>
 <br />
 <p><?php echo $description; ?></p>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <p> <h5>Size :</h5> <?php echo $paint_size; ?> </p>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <h5> <b>Likes : </b> <i> <?php echo $likes; ?> </i> </h5>
 </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td>
 <a href="editupload.php?id=<?php echo $my_uploads['id']; ?>">Edit Details</a>
 <a name="<?php echo $my_uploads['id'];?>" onClick="deletepr(this.name)" >Delete</a>
 </td>
 </tr>

 </table>

 </div>
  <?php

  }

  ?>


  </div>
```

Comment: Don't use tables for layout. Use tables if you have tabular data.

Comment: set the div width:20% and float:left

Answer (score 1):

With any side-by-side CSS arrangement, you should first decide how many elements you need to align, what the relationship between each is, and how much cross-browser compatibility means.

Some solutions are as follows, assuming the layout of

```
<div class='outer'><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
<div class='outer'><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
```

1. float:right. (http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4374976/css.html)
   `<style>.outer>div{float:right}</style>`
2. Display:inline or display:inline-block;
   `<style>.outer > div {display:inline-block}</style>`
   This is probably the simplest solution.
   inline-block allows you to set a width.
3. display:table-cell.
   This imitates a table, which may or may not be what you need. This is the only solution so far which will lign up the cells on the two rows, but it has less perfect browser support.
4. display:flex (http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
   This is the most complex but powerful solution. It has support everywhere expect IE prior to version 10. It is considered the new standard, and is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the CSS property display. (like SamGoody also suggested)

```
display: inline-block;
```

When given a fixed width you could align these easily.

Check this example I quickly setup:
http://jsfiddle.net/epicsoftworks/p7mZC/1/

You might also want to checkout bootstrap as this framework handles pretty much most situations automaticly  when following their rules.
http://getbootstrap.com/